# The external IP of istio ingress gateway stay pending

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I deployed a istio to k8s and it works well at first, but after one day, I can't access the app via ingress gateway. Then checked the istio svc status. It shows the external ip of the istio ingress gateway is pending.

I checked logs and events of the service, but there is nothing. What's the most possibility cause of the issue?

the external ip stay pending:

[image: the external ip stay pending]

Comment: This could be caused by your Ingress being unable to connect to the LoadBalancer which depends on where your K8s cluster is running. If you are running in GCP or AWS you should verify there is indeed a load balancer running and it's accepting traffic. If you are running on prem your cluster would be unable to auto-provision a load balancer and you would be responsible for providing one.

Comment: @davidmontoyago , I fully agree. It appears I posted my answer almost at same time as you did Your comment.

Comment: It is running on a Linux server but not any public cloud platform. It can get external IP at first, and the external IP become pending later.

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely caused by using platform that does not provide an external loadbalancer to istio ingress gateway.

According to [istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports) documentation:

> If the `EXTERNAL-IP` value is set, your environment has an external load balancer that you can use for the ingress gateway. If the `EXTERNAL-IP` value is `<none>` (or perpetually `<pending>`), your environment does not provide an external load balancer for the ingress gateway. In this case, you can access the gateway using the service’s [node port](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).

---

Follow these instructions if you have determined that your environment has an external load balancer.

Set the ingress IP and ports:

```
export INGRESS_HOST=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
export INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].port}')
export SECURE_INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="https")].port}')
export TCP_INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="tcp")].port}')
```

In certain environments, the load balancer may be exposed using a host name, instead of an IP address. In this case, the ingress gateway’s  `EXTERNAL-IP`  value will not be an IP address, but rather a host name, and the above command will have failed to set the  `INGRESS_HOST`  environment variable. Use the following command to correct the  `INGRESS_HOST`  value:

```
export INGRESS_HOST=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}')
```

Comment: It is deployed on a linux server, it can get the external-ip at first and the external-ip become pending later.

Answer (score 3):

removing the `traefik` service resolved my issue on k3d on localhost (dev environment).

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system

kubectl -n kube-sytem delete svc traefik
```

**I'm not an expert! This might have some side effects or cause other issues.**

Comment: This works because traefik uses the same port 443 on the host and prevents Istio to use it for the gateway. I had the same problem on k3s installation,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `KIND`, then you need to install [`MetalLB`](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/loadbalancer/) on top of it first. Then, your `istio-ingressgateway` will get an external IP assigned if it is of type `LoadBalancer`. Hopefully, this helps.